# Increase the y font Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to increase my Y font from my graphic but it is not working.

My code:

```py
import tkinter as tk 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg 
from matplotlib import animation 
import random

# Create the Tkinter window root = tk.Tk() root.geometry('400x100')
fig1, b1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 0.5), dpi = 80)
#b1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)


fig2, b2 = plt.subplots(figsize= (10, 0.5), dpi = 80)
#b2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)


def grafico_1 (i):
    global b1
    global nume
    global valu
    global fig1
    global y_fix
    global x

    x = []
    y_fix = []
    ws = ['WIRE']

    for valu in range (1, 6):
        nume = random.randint(1, 10)
        x.append(nume)
    #print(x)

    #Primeira camada do grafico 
    if int(x[0]) < 3:
        y_fix.append(int(x[0]), )
        #print(f'Lista de y_n ,e {y_n}')
        b1.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color = 'green')
        

    if int(x[0]) >= 3 and int(x[0]) < 6:
        y_fix.append(x[0])
        b1.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color='yellow')
        

    if int(x[0]) >= 6:
        y_fix.append(x[0])
        b1.barh(ws, int(x[0]), color='red')
        

    #Segunda camada:
    for c in x[1:]:
        if int(c) < 3:
            b1.barh(ws, int(c), color= 'green', left=y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump)
            
            
        if int(c) > 3 and int(c) < 5:
            b1.barh(ws, int(c), color='yellow', left= y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump)
            

        if int(c) >= 5:
            b1.barh(ws, int(c), color='red', left= y_fix)
            y_fix.append(int(c))
            jump = sum(y_fix)
            y_fix = []
            y_fix.append(jump) 



def grafico_2 (i2):
    global b2
    global nume2
    global valu2
    global fig2
    global y_fix2
    global x2

    x2 = []
    y_fix2 = []
    ws2 = ['line 2']

    for valu2 in range (1, 6):
        nume2 = random.randint(1, 10)
        x2.append(nume2)
    #print(f'Grafico 2 {x2}')
   

    #Primeira camada do grafico 
    if int(x2[0]) < 3:
        y_fix2.append(int(x2[0]))
        #print(f'Lista de y_n ,e {y_n}')
        b2.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color = 'green')

    if int(x2[0]) >= 3 and int(x2[0]) < 6:
        y_fix2.append(x2[0])
        b2.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color = 'yellow' )

    if int(x2[0]) >= 6:
        y_fix2.append(x2[0])
        b2.barh(ws2, int(x2[0]), color= 'red' )

    #Segunda camada:
    for c2 in x2[1:]:

        if int(c2) < 3:
            b2.barh(ws2, int(c2), color= 'green', left=y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)
            
        if int(c2) > 3 and int(c2) < 5:
            b2.barh(ws2, int(c2), color='yellow', left= y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)

        if int(c2) >= 5:
            b2.barh(ws2, int(c2), color='red', left= y_fix2)
            y_fix2.append(int(c2))
            jump2 = sum(y_fix2)
            y_fix2 = []
            y_fix2.append(jump2)


    #plt.show()

ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, grafico_1, interval = 3000, frames=100) ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, grafico_2, interval = 3000, frames=100)

# Embed the figures into Tkinter using FigureCanvasTkAgg canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=root) canvas1.get_tk_widget().place(x= 300, y= 460)

canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=root) canvas2.get_tk_widget().place(x= 300, y = 530)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have added your data to the axes, but before you embed the figure into the Tkinter canvas, add a line to set the y-axis label font size like this:

```
b1.set_yticklabels(b1.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=21)
```

In case this is not working, you can check two things:

1. `print(dir(b1))` to check which methods are available for it. In case you have accidentally overwritten or modified b1 somewhere else in your code than the part that you showed, it might not be recognized anymore that it is an axis, in which case you will have more problems regarding the methods that should be available.
2. `print(matplotlib.__version__)` to see if you are using an older version of matplotlib, in which some methods are not available.

A quick fix would be to use this line instead, which should work in older versions of matplotlib as well:

```
b1.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=21)
```

Comment: I tried to put b1.set_ but it not available for me

Comment: I added things to check and an alternative approach